# Creating custom attributes in Sailsjs

Tags: sails.js

I am trying to create a custom attribute in my sails app and I am not getting any result back in my get call.

My code looks something like this:

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
      id: {
          type: 'string',
          primaryKey: true,
          defaultsTo: function () {
              return uuid.v4();
          },
          unique: true,
          index: true,
          uuidv4: true
      },
      name: {
          type: 'string',
          required: true
      }
      fullName: function(){
          return this.name ;
      }


};
```

I get back all the fields expect full Name

Comment: Do you mean 'except' instead of 'expect'?

Comment: yes that;s what i meant

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the sailsjs model attributes only create corresponding column and get the column in database based on the type. In your case, the fullName has no type. so it does not know what to get from database.

However, if what you want is the returned json object has some extra fields, you can overwrite the toJSON function to add it.

```
module.exports={
    attributes:
        id: {
            type: 'string',
            primaryKey: true,
            defaultsTo: function () {
                return uuid.v4();
            },
            unique: true,
            index: true,
            uuidv4: true
        },
        name: {
            type: 'string',
            required: true
        },
        toJSON:function(){
            var obj=this.toObject();
            obj.fullName=obj.name;
            return obj;   
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is a little old, but I've a better answer:

```
    module.exports = {
      attributes: {
        firstname : 'string',
        lastname  : 'string,

        fullName: function () {
          return this.firstname + ' ' + this.lastname
        }        

        toJSON:function(){
            var obj      = this.toObject();
            obj.fullName = this.fullName()
            return obj;   
        }
      }
    }
```